# Why isn't -Contains returning true for this?

Tags: powershell

Here's my code:

```
while ($looper){
    [array]$destfiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\{redacted}\Documents\test powershell\DEST"
    [array]$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\{redacted}\Documents\test powershell\SRC" -File -Recurse
    Write-Host $destfiles
    Write-Host $srcfiles
    
    $matchcount = 0
    $matchfiles = ""

    $list = "a.txt","b.txt"

    foreach ($file in $destfiles){
        Write-Host "foreach " $file
        if ($list -contains $file){
            Write-Host "match iteration"
            $matchcount += 1
            # $matchfiles += $file + " "
        }
    }

    if ($matchcount -eq 0){
        Write-Host "break loop"
        break
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "loop"
        Start-Sleep -s 30
    }

    $loopcounter += 1
}
```

I have identical files in both directories. For the if statement, if I hardcode it (like in the above example) to this:

```
if ($list -contains $file){
```

It works as expected. But as soon as I try to actually compare against srcfiles, it doesn't enter the if loop:

```
if ($srcfiles -contains $file){
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While the file *names* might be identical, they're not the same files, because they're in two different directories. You might need to simplify the `$srcfiles` collection to be only filenames.

Comment: `$list -contains $file` -> `$list -contains $file.Name`

Comment: Wow that worked...thank you guys. I must admit it's very irritating as I had the Write-Host $srcfiles to check the content of the list and it only showed the filenames not the full paths. I've added -Name and it's working now.

Comment: I can't mark your comments as the solution, could you respond as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing to a `[FileInfo]` object, not a file *name*.

Change this `if` condition:

```
$list -contains $file
```

to:

```
$list -contains $file.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Two objects usually aren't equal unless they're the same object (they're pointers).  But comparing string values works.  Pay attention to the type of the left operand (the right side gets converted).

```
$a = get-childitem file
$b = get-childitem file


$a.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     FileInfo                                 System.IO.FileSystemInfo


"$a".gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object


$a -eq $a

True


$a -eq $b

False


"$a" -eq $b

True
```